# Cable screen terminations for enclosure containing SMPS and instrumentation signal conditioners

Tags: emc, termination, instrumentation

I'm looking for some help with some screening and cable termination decisions I need to make. I'd be grateful for any advice, and I'll do my best to explain myself clearly.

I am building a control panel for a tensile test machine. Please see the diagram for the functional blocks, and my explanation below for the finer details and my options as I see them. I have omitted power supply and watchdog connections; the signal conditioners and watchdog will be powered from the SMPS.

[image]

Key points:

- Before installing the enclosure, I terminated the LVDT screen at the signal conditioner (DR7AC signal conditioner, http://www.rdpe.com/cds/cd2402.pdf
- I use a screened cable from each signal conditioner to the DAQ, with the screen floating at the DAQ end and terminated at the conditioner end
- I plan to adopt the same strategy with the load cell conditioner, which is mounted in a diecast aluminum box
- The signals I am interested in are very low frequency (<30 Hz, mostly DC with smooth transitions)

My questions:

1. I'm confused whether or not I should consider the main wall enclosure as a screen termination point. That is, I want to place DIN receptacles on the panel, but this will cause my cable screens to be terminated at the large enclosure. I was planning to pass un-screened mains flex through a grommet to the disconnect switch, and I also have a SMPS inside the main wall enclosure, so I'm pretty sure I can't consider the large enclosure to be a screened environment.
2. Assuming that the answer to (1) is no, how then should I handle my cables and screens? If I use DIN plugs and receptacles on the main panel, then do I just continue with the screened cable on the inside, but leave it floating at the DIN connector end and terminate the screen at the signal conditioner? This is what my intuition is telling me.
3. Should I mount my diecast aluminum box containing the load cell signal conditioner straight to the back plate of the wall enclosure, which is grounded? Or should I insulate my internal screened enclosures, and use an earth lead to the panel star-point?

I hope this makes sense; I'm afraid I've been thinking about it for so long that I might have taken a detail for granted - please ask if anything needs elaboration. If anyone is prepared to help then I would be keen to have a dialogue.

Finally, I would like a solution using the parts I have mentioned; DIN connectors (3 pin and 5 pin), 2 and 4 core twisted and screened cable, grommets, and enclosures ([a large wall enclosure](http://uk.farnell.com/schneider-electric/nsys3d4420p/enclosure-ip66-400x400x200mm/dp/1853668?ost=1853668) is the main enclosure, and a small diecast enclosure for the load cell signal conditioner). The LVDT signal conditioner is a DIN rail mounted version.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My question hasn't been put on hold, but neither have I had a response. If anything is unclear, I would be very happy to elaborate. I've recently started a new job and I'm just asking for guidance. I have copies of Tim Williams's books on EMC, but I'm concerned about how to terminate my cable shields at the outer enclosure and inner enclosure without creating a ground loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason you haven't gotten any response is that it is hard to give any definite answers and it is a big subject. But here are some pointers. The reasons for shielding (U.S. term, my guess that is same as screening) is either to keep EMI out or to keep EMI in. I think your main objective is to keep EMI out of certain modules and signal lines. Looks like that would be the signal conditioners and the corresponding cables.

1. Assuming the cables are terminated at the main enclosure, so shielding is established between inside and outside. There are noise coupling between the components inside among themselves. If the level of noise coupling is low enough that it can be tolerated, then nothing much has to be done. Otherwise, additional shielding inside the enclosure can be a solution.
2. Looks like the signal conditioners are shielded already, so the additional shielding inside would be the two signal cables. So your idea of using screened cable inside is fine. As to termination of the screens, I think in this case, the shielding effectiveness would be more consistent if the screens are terminated on both ends.
3. Mount the signal conditioner straight to the wall enclosure. In conjunction of terminating the cable screens at both ends, to make the shields one big solid low impedance mass is more consistent than star configuration.

There should not be issue of ground loop on the shields inside the enclosure. But there are likely to be ground loops with the external components. But if the ground loop current is small and only flow on the shields, it might not affect the signals enough to be a problem.